# Multiple inputs and "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing"

Tags: python-3.x, input, eof

I am using **python 3**. My goal is to receive some inputs and build a dictionary to represent a phone book. The first line of input is the number of people the program is going to receive the data about.

My input is this file d8_input.txt:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
```

My code to read the data above is:

```
#store the number of items on dic
num = int(input())

#create an empty dictionary
dic_phone_book = {}

#store the names and telephone in dic
for j in range(0, num):
    name_and_telephone = str(input())
    print (name_and_telephone)
```

I still have to split the string in order to store the name and the telephone number in separate variables. However, I am having a big problem to read the file.

When I run  `python3 d8.py < d8_input.txt`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d8.py", line 10, in <module>
    name = str(input())
  File "<string>", line 1
    sam 99912222
               ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

If I just run `python3 d8.py` and manually input the data, I still get the same error. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works for me. I don't know what you did wrong.

Comment: That is a Python 2.x error.

Comment: ok, thanks, I probably messed up with the version 2 and 3. Now, it is running

Comment: @Harry You can self-answer the question if you got it working. If it was just a typo then it's probably better to delete the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `sys.stdin.readline` instead because `input` is meant for interactive input. See [sys.stdin.readline() and input(): which one is faster when reading lines of input, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623528/sys-stdin-readline-and-input-which-one-is-faster-when-reading-lines-of-inpu)

Answer (score 2):

It was just a problem with the version of python. The default in my terminal is python 2. I thought I was running Python 3 but I was not. I tried to delete this question, however, since it is an open bounty, I can't delete it. So, I am answering it.