# Day 8 Hackerrank Python of 30 Days of Code - Dictionaries and Maps

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, maps

Can anyone figure out why my code for this exercise from Python Hackerrank 30 Days of Challenge doesn't pass Test Case 1?

Here is the challenge:

Objective
Today, we're learning about Key-Value pair mappings using a Map or Dictionary data structure. Check out the Tutorial tab for learning materials and an instructional video!

Task
Given  names and phone numbers, assemble a phone book that maps friends' names to their respective phone numbers. You will then be given an unknown number of names to query your phone book for. For each  queried, print the associated entry from your phone book on a new line in the form name=phoneNumber; if an entry for  is not found, print Not found instead.

Note: Your phone book should be a Dictionary/Map/HashMap data structure.

Input Format

The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of entries in the phone book.
Each of the  subsequent lines describes an entry in the form of  space-separated values on a single line. The first value is a friend's name, and the second value is an -digit phone number.

After the  lines of phone book entries, there are an unknown number of lines of queries. Each line (query) contains a  to look up, and you must continue reading lines until there is no more input.

Note: Names consist of lowercase English alphabetic letters and are first names only.

Output Format

On a new line for each query, print Not found if the name has no corresponding entry in the phone book; otherwise, print the full  and  in the format name=phoneNumber.

Here is my code:

```
    n = int(input())

    phone_book = {}

    for i in range(n):
        name, phone_num = map(str,input().split())
        name = name.lower()
        phone_book[name] = phone_num

    queries = 0

    while queries in range(n):
        query = input().lower()
        if query in phone_book:
            print(query + "=" + phone_book.get(query))
        else:
            print("Not found")

        queries += 1
```

For this Test Case 1:

```
100000
unayklejwm 53561825
ahiff 57272140
frlrecdfxo 28001354
aeccxyrbek 21112785
mlgdk 12405837
iyiyycfngr 23841264
subnwvrqdp 77688226
vhypdqfbdy 67846211
lcnbh 86026675
lxbjpmuhis 85475547
enfifbprov 20172436
hnjctgslxf 18125412
slfoglbvah 47530087
mpsrcmrkon 44365224
jnpslqvlkx 88071512
liwyjbsfkk 50646067
kyrkhaikuf 18535535
ubvfx 43551151
krger 80787433{-truncated-}
```

The error I got wasn't the fact it was wrong output but it was this:

Compiler Message:

```
Runtime Error
```

Expected Output

```
Not found
ipwpabdefa=14170412
Not found
toykmviqbo=11872347
mooetebtqt=70658483
fbubawkkhq=10613664
Not found
ejqxn=77321147
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
xgfpx=58118174
Not found
odacddldrk=73267266
Not found
iakxugylkc=41875647
Not found
djtelththc=20278224
Not found{-truncated-}
```

This only happened for the first test case but the other cases were successful in passing.

Edit: I just ran all test cases again and this time I passed all the test cases according to the results. However, I still get a runtime error even though I passed all the test cases fine. It gave me this:

```
Runtime Error :(
```

Is there a reason why this error popped up? How should I fix my code?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You need to [edit] to post the actual problem statement here, rather than expect people to go to Hackerrank. Without it, there's not enough details on what the code is supposed to do. It reads 100000 inputs and stores it in a dict, ... then what gets passed to the next `query = input().lower()` calls ? Also, notice that you called `query = input().lower()` outside of the loop, then you did that again inside, effectively skipping over the 1st input.

Comment: Ok I added the problem and revised my code and I still get the same runtime error (even if I passed all the test cases one time).

Comment: The challenge says: "*there are an unknown number of lines of queries.* and "*you must continue reading lines until there is no more input*". However, you seem to be expecting `n` queries (`while queries in range(n)`). I think `n` is only supposed to be the number of phone book entries.

Comment: @Gino Mempin Is there a way to get around that? If there is an unknown number of test cases, it could go to infinity for all I know. But there was a constraint to it according to the problem. Both n and number of queries have a constraint of 10^5. The problem is the runtime error even after I passed all the test cases.

Comment: Additionally when you are testing manually: To enter an EOF, use: ^Z (Ctrl+Z) in Windows ^D (CTRL+D)on Unix-like systems

Answer (score 3):

```
N=int(input())
phoneBook={}

for _ in range(N):
    name,contact=input().split()
    phoneBook[name]=contact

try:
    while(True):
        check=str(input())
        if check in phoneBook:
            print(check+"="+phoneBook[check])
        else:
            print('Not found')

except(EOFError):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
N=int(input())
d={}
for i in range(N):
    entry=input().split()
    d[entry[0]]=entry[1]

ans=[]

try:
    while(1):
        new=str(input())
        if(new in d.keys()):
            ans.append(new+"="+str(d[new]))
        else:
            ans.append('Not found')
except(EOFError):
    pass

for a in ans:
    print(a)
```

the while(1) loop solves the problem of running it continuously and the try except block will help in terminating the flow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using `input()` as the way to get user inputs.
The problem with input is that it would raise an EOFError when there is not more inputs left to be read.

Rather than using input, consider using `sys.stdin.readline().strip()` which returns an empty string `''` during an EOF situation. Which you can then use to evaluate your while loop.

[sys.stdin.readline() and input(): which one is faster when reading lines of input, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623528/sys-stdin-readline-and-input-which-one-is-faster-when-reading-lines-of-inpu)

Or capture the EOFError as answered by @Siddhant