# sys.std.readline() Vs. input()

Tags: python, string, user-input, sys

```
>>> import sys
>>> word = sys.stdin.readline()
Hello
>>> print(word[-1])


>>> print(word[-2])
o
```

The above method differs quite a bit from the expected output using input() method.

```
>>> letter = input()
hola
>>> print(letter[-1])
a
```

Could you please explain it ?

Comment: `readline()` includes the newline at the end, `input()` doesn't.

Comment: After the `word = sys.stdin.readline()`, try evaluating `word` and you'll see `'your input\n'` - the `\n` indicates a newline character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sys.stdin.readline() and input(): which one is faster when reading lines of input, and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623528/sys-stdin-readline-and-input-which-one-is-faster-when-reading-lines-of-inpu)