# Python Ray Collisions Logic Incorrect (USACO 2020 December Bronze Q3 "Stuck in a Rut")

Tags: python, arrays, list, algorithm, logic

I am trying to solve this question from the USACO website. Problem Link: http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=1061

Farmer John has recently expanded the size of his farm, so from the perspective of his cows it is effectively now infinite in size! The cows think of the grazing area of the farm as an infinite 2D grid of square "cells", each filled with delicious grass (think of each cell as a square in an infinite chessboard). Each of Farmer John's N cows (1≤N≤50) starts out in a different cell; some start facing north, and some start facing east.

Every hour, every cow either

- Stops if the grass in her current cell was already eaten by another
  cow.
- Eats all the grass in her current cell and moves one cell forward
  according to the direction she faces.

Over time, each cow therefore leaves a barren "rut" of empty cells behind her.

If two cows move onto the same grassy cell in the same move, they share the cell and continue moving in their respective directions in the next hour.

Please determine the amount of grass eaten by each cow. Some cows never stop, and therefore eat an infinite amount of grass.

**INPUT FORMAT (input arrives from the terminal / stdin):**

The first line of input contains N. Each of the next N lines describes the starting location of a cow, in terms of a character that is either N (for north-facing) or E (for east-facing) and two nonnegative integers x and y (0≤x≤1000000000, 0≤y≤1000000000) giving the coordinates of a cell. All x-coordinates are distinct from each-other, and similarly for the y-coordinates.
To be as clear as possible regarding directions and coordinates, if a cow is in cell (x,y) and moves north, she ends up in cell (x,y+1). If she instead had moved east, she would end up in cell (x+1,y).

**OUTPUT FORMAT (print output to the terminal / stdout):**

Print N lines of output. Line i in the output should describe the number of cells worth of grass that the ith cow in the input eats. If a cow eats an infinite amount of grass, output "Infinity" for that cow.

**SAMPLE INPUT:**

```
6
E 3 5
N 5 3
E 4 6
E 10 4
N 11 2
N 8 1
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**:

```
5
3
Infinity
Infinity
2
5
```

**SCORING:**

- In test cases 2-5, all coordinates are at most 100.
- In test cases 6-10, there are no additional constraints.

My logic is that since simulating the collisions would be too slow because the field is huge, we can sort the cows by their x values, iterate over all the collisions/intersections of cows and stop the ones that should be stopped, and after iterating, print out the distances of the stopped cows. And if a cow hasn't stopped, print "Infinity".

My code:

```
# Defining the cow class with the original order position, x, y, distance, 
# and whether or not it stopped.
class Cow:
  def __init__(self, i, x, y):
    self.i = i 
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.dist = 0
    self.stopped = False

# Get input from console and split cows into east facing and north facing cows.
n = int(input().strip())
hor = []
ver = []
ans = [0] * n
for i in range(n):
  line = input().strip().split()
  if line[0] == 'E':
    hor.append(Cow(i, int(line[1]), int(line[2])))
  else:
    ver.append(Cow(i, int(line[1]), int(line[2])))
hor.sort(key = lambda c: c.x)
ver.sort(key = lambda c: c.x)

# Iterate over every possible collision. Logic problem here:
for h in hor:
  for v in ver:
    vdist = abs(h.y - v.y)
    hdist = abs(h.x - v.x)
    if h.stopped and v.stopped:
      continue
    elif h.stopped:
      if v.x >= h.x and v.x <= h.x + h.dist and v.y <= h.y:
        if vdist > hdist:
          v.dist = vdist
          v.stopped = True
    elif v.stopped:
      if v.x >= h.x and h.y <= v.y + v.dist and v.y <= h.y:
        if hdist > vdist:
          h.dist = hdist
          h.stopped = True
    else:
      if v.x >= h.x and v.y <= h.y:
        if vdist > hdist:
          v.dist = vdist
          v.stopped = True
        if hdist > vdist:
          h.dist = hdist
          h.stopped = True
        
# Combine the lists and put them back into the original order.
cows = hor + ver
cows.sort(key = lambda c: c.i)

# Print out all the cows' distances, and it a cow hasn't stopped, replace distance with Infinity.
for i in cows:
  if not i.stopped:
    i.dist = "Infinity"
  print(i.dist)
```

I'm not sure if it's just my code that isn't correct, or if it's my basic logic. If anyone can provide a fix, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @DanielHao Does it use the same logic? Both would be fine though. Just asking

Comment: Very similar - some syntax changes to make it `work`... ;-)  Still testing and submit the site in `Analysis` mode.

Comment: @DanielHao That would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was `hor.sort(key = lambda c: c.x)` where I sorted the list by the 1st element instead of the 2nd.

It should be `hor.sort(key = lambda c: c.y)` since that's what matters at the intersections.

Answer (score 3):

Try this revised approach, using `set` to add the movements and check intersection.

```
from collections import deque
import sys

class Cow:
    def __init__(self, d, x, y, amt):
        self.d = d
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.amt = amt

lines = sys.stdin.read().strip().split('\n')
n = int(lines[0])

EMPTY = set()
COW = []

for line in lines[1:]:
    d, x, y = line.split()
    x, y = int(x), int(y)
    COW.append(Cow(d, x, y, 0))

S = set()
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        S.add(abs(COW[i].x - COW[j].x))
        S.add(abs(COW[i].y - COW[j].y))

S2 = set()
for k in S:
    S2.add(k -1)
    S2.add(k)
    S2.add(k + 1)
S2.add(max(S) + 1)

dq = deque(sorted(S2))   #

SCORE = [None for _ in range(n)]
t = 0

while dq:
    #nt += 1
    dt = dq.popleft() - t
    dt = max(dt, 1)
    t += dt
    VOID = []
    
    for i in range(n):
        if SCORE[i] is None:
            if (COW[i].x, COW[i].y) in EMPTY:
                SCORE[i] = COW[i].amt
                continue
            
            VOID.append((COW[i].x, COW[i].y))
            
            if COW[i].d == 'N': COW[i].y += dt
            elif COW[i].d == 'E': COW[i].x += dt
            COW[i].amt += dt
            
    for spot in VOID: EMPTY.add(spot)

for i in range(n):
    print(SCORE[i] if SCORE[i] else 'Infinity')
```

Comment: Thank you! Just curious. Is there any different in speed between using `input()` and `sys.stdin.read()`?

Comment: Don't believe there is much difference in Python 3.x.  Please review this related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22623528/sys-stdin-readline-and-input-which-one-is-faster-when-reading-lines-of-inpu

Comment: I was re-reading the code. Is `nt` actually used for anything?

Comment: Prob. left from earlier debugging. Removed now.

Comment: Revisiting this problem a bit later... all I had to do to my original code was sort the `hor` list by the 2nd element, not the first

Answer (score 1):

To keep track of your algorithm you could split 'intersection-finding' and 'cow-stopping' into separate parts.

[image: proveofconcept]

```
import sys
from collections import namedtuple

Cow = namedtuple('Cow', ['distance','facing','x','y','number'])
lines = sys.stdin.read().strip().split('\n')

cows = [Cow(0,*[int(x) if x.isnumeric() else x for x in i.split()], e)
            for e,i in enumerate(lines[1:])]

# finding intersections
# save if distances differ, sorted descending by distance
intersections = []
for cowA, cowB in [(cowA, cowB)
                    for cowB in cows if cowB.facing == 'N'
                    for cowA in cows if cowA.facing == 'E' 
                  ]:
    if cowA.x < cowB.x and cowA.y > cowB.y:
        d1, d2 = cowB.x - cowA.x, cowA.y - cowB.y
        if d1 != d2:
            intersections.append(
                sorted([Cow(d1, *cowA[1:]),Cow(d2, *cowB[1:])], reverse=True))

# sorting intersections by larger distance
# checking if a cow reached the intersection or stopped earlier
distances = [int(10E9)] * len(cows)
for i in sorted(intersections):
    if i[1].distance < distances[i[1].number] and i[0].distance < distances[i[0].number]:
        distances[i[0].number] = i[0].distance
for i in distances:
    print('Infinity' if i==int(10E9) else i)
```

Output

```
5
3
Infinity
Infinity
2
5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code did not pass all tests. It's failed on 8 out of 10 (on that platform).

Comment: @DanielHao - thanks again for your support. The bug was caused by a condition I didn't consider. I added the results for my solution.

Comment: That is Great 